# Control.Applicative precedence

Tags: haskell, operator-precedence, applicative

Regarding Control.Applicative, If I have the following expression:

```
f = (expr1 <|> expr2) <* expr3
```

Are the brackets necessary?  That is, will `expr3` get evaluated (and thrown away) regardless of which branch is taken?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can ask `ghci` for precedence information:

```
Prelude Control.Applicative> :i <|>
class Applicative f => Alternative f where
  ...
  (<|>) :: f a -> f a -> f a
  ...
    -- Defined in `Control.Applicative'
infixl 3 <|>
Prelude Control.Applicative> :i <*
class Functor f => Applicative f where
  ...
  (<*) :: f a -> f b -> f a
    -- Defined in `Control.Applicative'
infixl 4 <*
```

The relevant bits there are these two lines:

```
infixl 3 <|>
infixl 4 <*
```

Since `<*` has a higher precedence (4), it binds tighter; so yes, the brackets are needed to prevent that from being parsed as `expr1 <|> (expr2 <* expr3)`.

Answer (score 3):

`<|>` has a precedence of 3; `<*` of 4. So the parentheses are required.

```
$ ghci
λ import Control.Applicative
λ :info <|>
class Applicative f => Alternative f where
  ...
  (<|>) :: f a -> f a -> f a
  ...
    -- Defined in `Control.Applicative'
infixl 3 <|>
λ :info <*
class Functor f => Applicative f where
  ...
  (<*) :: f a -> f b -> f a
    -- Defined in `Control.Applicative'
infixl 4 <*
```

Comment: Thanks.  That was my instinct, but I was not sure.